# Highcharts getSVG and use with React-PDF dataLabels will not resize the font size is ignored

Tags: javascript, highcharts, font-size, react-highcharts, react-pdf

I have got my SVG string from getSVG

```
let chartSVG = chart.getSVG({ ...options })
```

I am formatting it so it renders in React-PDF only problem I am getting now is the dataLabels for a variablePie will not resize, I have tried multiple options by searching online and none of them will resize them, they are too big, I managed to resize the variblepie chart. by changing the width and height in

```
 chart.getSVG({
      chart:{
            width:236,
            height:162,
        },
  ... })
```

I just can not get the text to resize...

I have attached an image of how it looks in my React-PDF

part of the svg has -

```
<text x="5" data-z-index="1" y="14" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 5px; font-weight: bold; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Wealth</text>
```

it just seems to ignore the font-sizes..

[image: VariablePie]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Highchats` object instead of argument of callback (`chart`) as a reference:

```
Highcharts.charts[0].getSVG({
    chart: {
      width: 300,
      height: 300
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          style: {
            fontSize: '6px'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ywvr743o/

**Related thread:**
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/262

EDIT:

**React Demo:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-v95dqj

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but it doesn't appear to change it, maybe it's react-PDF affecting it. it seems to just ignore the styles.

Comment: Hi, In my case everything seems to work correctly. I've edited my answer with react demo added. Regards!

Comment: i think it's to do with React-PDF passing the highchart chart to that. :/

Comment: Is the React-PDF neccesery in your project? You can easly export PDFs using export-server module.

Comment: yes as I need to pass through other content from a backend

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately, since it's not due to the Highcharts issue, I am afraid I can't help you more. Regards!